# matching start of a string but not end in R

Tags: r, regex

How can I match all words starting with `plan_` and not ending with `template` without using `invert = TRUE`? In the below example, I'd like to match only the second string. I tried with negative lookahead but it does not work, maybe because of greediness?

```
names <- c("plan_x_template", "plan_x")
grep("^plan.*(?!template)$", 
  names, 
  value = TRUE, perl = TRUE
)
#> [1] "plan_x_template" "plan_x"
```

I mean one can also solve the problem with two regex calls but I'd like to see how it works the other way :-)

```
is_plan <- grepl("^plan_", names)
is_template <- grepl("_template$", names)
names[is_plan & !is_template]
#> [1] "plan_x"
```

Comment: Does this `grep("^plan_[A-Za-z]+\\b", names, value = TRUE)` work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
names <- c("plan_x_template", "plan_x")
grep("^plan(?!.*template)", 
  names, 
  value = TRUE, perl = TRUE
)
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/qFyCAr)

The `^plan(?!.*template)` pattern matches:

- `^` - a start of string
- `plan` - a `plan` substring
- `(?!.*template)` - a [negative **lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there are 0+ chars other than line break chars (since `perl = TRUE` is used and the pattern is processed with a PCRE engine, the `.` does not match all possible chars as opposed to the default `grep` TRE regex engine), as many as possible, followed with `template` substring.

**NOTE**: In case of multiline strings, you need to use a DOTALL modifier in the regex, `"(?s)^plan(?!.*template)"`.

Comment: Thanks. So can I read the negative loockahead *inside out* i.e.  checking if `.*template` matches and if it does `(?!.*template)` will be a non-match and vice versa?

Comment: @LorenzWalthert You may use `invert = TRUE` if you need an inverse behavior. `(?!.*template)` will match those cases when `template` is missing later in the string. `(?=.*template)` (a positive lookahead) will match those strings that have `template` somewhere to the left of the current location.